# Use single USB drive for both live CD and regular data

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning

I'd like to have both live-usb linux distribution and some random data stored on the same usb stick. So that if I plug it in and tell bios to load from it, live partition will be started, and if I just plug it in when some other OS is already running, only the data partition will be visible and will act as a regular usb stick.
Is it possible?

Comment: Depends on whether “some other OS” includes Linux or not.

Comment: It is possible to hide the boot partition from Windows, but not from Linux. Is that interesting for you?

Comment: It will also act as a Live Compact Disk even on Linux, as long as the Operating System is already started.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do a [multiboot USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it) with one or many ISO images inside. If you boot from it, you choose the ISO, but otherwise you can use the stick normally.

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems to me that's exactly what the OP asked ...